# Customize journald config for a single service

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I have a service (systemd unit) that logs very long messages (~700K), which means that the default `LineMax` setting of 48K doesn't suffice.

Setting the `LineMax` field to `1M` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` does the trick, but this probably applies to all services running on the system.

Another way that works is to create a file `/usr/lib/systemd/journald.conf.d/blah.conf` that contains:

```
[Journal]
LineMax=1M
```

But this again seems to apply to all services running on the system (since I can name the file anything).

Is there any way to apply the `LineMax` configuration only to one specific service, and leave other services to use the default?

Comment: Have you solved it (this is interesting)? However, I did not found anything related to `journald` configuration yet. I only found about redirecting `StandardOutput` and/or `StandardError` of your systemd service to `null` or some file. Redirecting to a file might be useful but I have to monitor the file ( by using something like`inoitify`,`logrotate`) and when this one exceeds the limit file size then truncate it.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, no unfortunately I never managed to figure it out. I've changed jobs since then, so this currently doesn't affect me :) Redirecting to a file and then monitoring it could be doable, but seems like a rather ugly hack. It might be worth opening an issue for this on the systemd GitHub repo imo.

Comment: Oh, that's nice. And yeah, as you said it would be better If this is asked in GitHub. Maybe it does not exist this feature so can be considered for future releases. Thanks for your response!